# How do you make dynamic dropdown menus?

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

Here is what I made so far : http://jsfiddle.net/vKJ9G/5/

I am trying to make a copy of the drop down menu at  http://www.getarealdegree.com/.

I want the first drop down to determine what goes in the next menu and so on.

I'm no javaScript expert and got stuck.

I've written all my code in :

```
 $('#sel1').change(function ()
 {  

 }
```

Comment: Good that you created a jsfiddle, but important parts of your code should be here as well. Speaking of your question, what you did is the first part, but now you have to create the options for the dropdowns on the change event.

Comment: Do your research first, this isn't one stop shop for getting your code written for you. Down-voted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made an example for dynamically changing the selected value of a drop down menu here.

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
    window.onload = function() { BindEvent(); }

    function BindEvent()
    {
        var elemToBind = document.getElementById ( "cmb1" );
        elemToBind.onchange = function () { SetSel ( this ); }
    }
    function SetSel(elem)
    {
        var secondCombo = document.getElementById ( "cmb2" );
        secondCombo.value = elem.value;   
    }
</script>
<body>
    <select id="cmb1">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
    <select id="cmb2">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
</body>
```

Here is the link to the Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/yS5rQ/

Hope it helps.

Comment: I recommend using `onBlur` versus `onChange` for better accessibility